# Would this power chain be safe and work?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply

I am currently making my first own PCB with its own .icrocontroller on it. I will also need a USB port for powering and data transfer.

I want to be sure that I won't destroy my components. I would like to know if it will succesfully power my microcontroller and that I will be ablr to communicate with it through USB.

The microcontroller is a ATSAMD21G18A-AU and its a mico USB port.

[image: The Power Chain in question]

Rework of the power chain:

[image: Power Chain V2 in question]

Will it work now?

Comment: Why do L1 and L2 have 1.5kOhm values?

Comment: You’ll probably want to connect GNDANA to ground, and consider adding 10 or 100nF decoupling capacitors between each pair of VDD and GND pins.

Comment: @JLCPCBEngineer They're probably ferrite beads. Low DC resistance but 1.5K at 100MHz.

Comment: You're still using a precision voltage reference as your regulator in your new schematic. They're not designed to do that, they're a precise source of an exact voltage for things like meters to use as a comparison. It's very unlikely it will be happy sinking lots of current as a power supply.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't work.

Multiple supply and ground pins are not connected, and for some mysterious reason your inductors/ferrites have resistance values, and USB data pin resistor values are off by approximately a factor of 1000.

The REF3333 also is not a regulator, it can't power the circuit.

Your updated schematic still has unconnected pins and without proper regulator. This Q&A site really is not suitable for design review questions where you constantly keep changing your schematic which then requires updating of answers.

Comment: Thanks! I should have fixed them now

Comment: Are the inductors actually ferrites that are often advertised by a resistance value that they reach above certain frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Also, you don't want to use a precision voltage reference as power supply.

Instead opt for an [LDO Voltage Regulator](https://eu.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/power-management-ics/voltage-regulators-voltage-controllers/ldo-voltage-regulators/).

Comment: Would a HE2021A36HPR work if I want around 3.6V output and supply it with the normal USB voltage?

Comment: The HE2021A36HPR (https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2007271206_HEERMICR-HE2021A36HPR_C711943.pdf) seems fine if your current draw doesn't exceed 200mA.

Comment: If you really want a non-standard 3.6V supply for some reason and 200mA is enough, it could work. But why would you want 3.6V?

Comment: Thanks! I didnt consider that, so I will be taking a HE6236MPR now, as its rated for 500mA and I am going to power a few LEDs. I want 3.6V, or something in that area, because its the maximum my Microcontroller, the ATSAMD21G18A-AU, supports.

Comment: The datasheet says it can be be operated on up to 3.63V, but anything above 3.8V (a mere 0.2V above 3.6V) will kill it. It is really designed to run on 3.3V, with an allowed upper limit to account for supply voltage variations. Unless for some reason you _have_ to use 3.6V you should use the standard 3.3V.

Comment: ATSAMD21G18A-AU rated power supply voltage: 1.62V ... 3.63V (typ. 3.3V). HE6236MPR Max Output Voltage: Vout * 1.02 (3.672V) which is slightly above the recommended ATSAMD21G18A-AU rating.

Comment: @Bugsia I don’t think you gain anything by running your micro at its max voltage, you’ll get the same performance at 3.3, 3.0, 2.7V.

Comment: The LED supply voltage does not need to be exactly the same as the uC.

Comment: Please understand that running at 3.6V is an extremely poor idea. That is 1% away from being off the safe range of 3.63, and the regulator tolerance is only 2% so it can exceed safe range. Plus, the USB operation is as per USB specifications rated up to 3.6V. The device is intended to be operated on 3.3V.